# Why do we use print statements while defining a function in python? Does it help in debugging?

Tags: python, debugging

I am learning python programming and I read somewhere that many a times we use return statement without any output for the purpose of seeing the side effects. Could you explain why is that so? For eg.

```
def sum(a, b)
      print "enter sum!"
      print "a is", a
      a = a + b
      print "a is", a
print sum(2, 123)
```

What is the necessity of writing a print statement here?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking here. You use print to, well, print some output. What is confusing about that?

Comment: Yes, this looks like it's for code debugging...!? I'm unclear what your question is. FWIW, you should do debugging/logging statements via the `logging` module instead of plain `print`, but that doesn't change the fundamental use case.

Comment: Your function doesn't actually return anything, so the last line of output will be "None"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your piece of code is rather strange: it really does not need so many printing. Answering to your question: `print` is generally used in 2 cases:

1.Interaction with user in console scripts. For example:

```
def do_some_stuff():
   ...

def main():
   print 'Started doing some stuff...'
   result = do_some_stuff()
   print 'Completed. Result: %s' % result
```

2.Debugging. If you are unclear what is happening in your code, you can *temporarily* insert print into any part of your code. For example:

```
def sum(a, b):
    print 'Args: %s, %s' % (a, b)
    return a + b
```

Note: both cases can be substituted with more powerful tool: [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).